# Slice variable in smarty, than show it on website

Tags: php, smarty

I'm trying to learn Smarty(My brother send me this homework to practice) and I have a problem at the beginning of the road. First of all, I want to create a variable with some text - then slice this text into a half (after chosen word). Put those halves into an array. Then take this first part of the text and all spaces to change to "_" and in the other half change all strange signs like "ą, ć, ę" to for example "a, c, e". And after then show them on the website. All of this by Smarty.

My smarty is very novice so to this moment I was just trying to put text into variable:

```
{assign var="textToEdit" value="Loręm ipsum dólór śit amęt, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus ornare vehicula risus, sed impęrdiet lorem malesuada mollis. Morbi ultrices elit leo, ac eleifend neque tincidunt in. Morbi volutpat mauris suscipit nulla pellentesque suscipit. Cras tortor enim, pellentesque a dictum id, iaculis et purus. Vivamus ac venenatis sem. Duis pharetra sit amet augue vitae tincidunt. Prąęśent vęnńnatis ipsum nęc augue condimentum, a scelerisque sapien blandit. Curabitur suscipit vivęrra urna, molestie ullamcorper nulla luctus ut. Pellentęsque ac accumsan turpis, nec posuere enim."}
<h1>
    The value of $textToEdit is {$textToEdit}.
</h1>
```

Then I tried showing this with h1 on the website. But it didn't work. if I had to do it with javascript it wouldn't be a problem, Smarty is something completely new for me, please help me solve the problem. I'd like to look and analyze the code line by line.

Comment: Smarty is a templating language - while this is possible, it should not be used for such tons of logic

Comment: But I want to try to make it works for myself :)

Comment: At this point I find out when I use {$textToEdit|truncate:30:""} - this destroy my website